# Broken pipe java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, ioexception

After updating SDK & HAXM, I have been facing from the error mentioned below. 
The apk is build successfully only in emulator not the real device.

> I have performed following task already but didn't help at all:
>
> - Cleaned and Rebuild Project.
> - Invalidate caches and restart.
> - Restart my workstation and mobile too.
> - Deleted the build and re-built it again.
> - Instant run is turned off.

```
 Broken pipe java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:524)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:627)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.uploadApk(SplitApkInstaller.java:151)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:77)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:930)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask$SplitApkInstaller.installApp(SplitApkDeployTask.java:138)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.RetryingInstaller.install(RetryingInstaller.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask.perform(SplitApkDeployTask.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have both Android studio and Eclipse open.

Comment: No. The only thing opened is Android Studio. I haven't installed eclipse yet.

Comment: change usb cable

Comment: I have multiple device. Before update, they both were working just fine. I doubt this is the problem with the usb cable. They are detected by adb but gets disconnected when I build them.

Comment: Doesn't restarting the system restarts/kills the adb?

Comment: but just run `adb kill-server` and then run the app.

Comment: Sure. I will do that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried the same steps you did. Ultimately, running this command is what fixed it for me.

```
sudo adb kill-server && sleep 5 && adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to deal with this which I am even facing today is simply by **Restarting ADB**.

If you want to kill the adb,

```
adb kill-server
```

For starting,

```
adb start-server
```

This way it solves for me.